# Mensagem da API do Whatsapp incompleta

Tags: php, html, css, api, whatsapp

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site e nele tem um botão de compartilhar uma mensagem para um determinado contato, o problema é que esta mensagem está aparecendo incompleta. Usei o Inspecionar Elemento no site e a mensagem está completa, mas ao testar a mensagem tanto via Whatsapp Web, quanto pelo Smartphone ela aparece incompleta.

```
$destaque['share_whatsapp'] = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" . preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row_share['config_whatsapp']) . "&text=Olá, gostaria de conversar á respeito deste imóvel: https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/imoveis.php?categoria=" . $destaque['imov_id_categ'] . "&imovel=" . $destaque['imov_id'] . "&galeria=" . $destaque['imov_id_galeria'];
```

Como está aparecendo no código fonte do site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pensei que a API do Whatsapp teria alguma limitação a respeito do número de caracteres, mas ao remover alguns caracteres da mensagem mesmo assim a mensagem não passa de "categoria".

Comment: Você está mandando um link pelo próprio link? Olha a loucura que isso será. Pesquise sobre codificar o texto antes de gerar sua URL dinamicamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, você precisa fechar a tag anchor. 
Para utilizar o Api do Whats é necessário abrir uma URL, e como toda URL, é necessário fazer a codificação da URL (Url encode).

Então no seu caso ficaria assim, exemplo abaixo:
 (51) 99778-5300

```
$destaque['share_whatsapp'] = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" . preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row_share['config_whatsapp']) . "&text=Olá,%20gostaria%20de%20conversar%20á%20respeito%20deste%20imóvel:%20https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/imoveis.php?categoria=" . $destaque['imov_id_categ'] . "&imovel=" . $destaque['imov_id'] . "&galeria=" . $destaque['imov_id_galeria'];
```

No php você pode usar a função urlencode para codificar a url.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Nunca utilizei essa api, mas talvez seja necessário codificar a url que está dentro da chamada da api (função nativa PHP rawurlencode()), exemplo:

```
//Parâmetros
$row_share['Something is wrong_whatsapp'] = 123456789;
$destaque['server'] = 'localhost';
$destaque['imov_id_categ'] = 99;
$destaque['imov_id'] = 99;
$destaque['imov_id_galeria'] = 99;

//construção da url
$url = "Olá, gostaria de conversar á respeito deste imóvel: https://" .
    $destaque['server'] . "/imoveis.php?categoria=" .
    $destaque['imov_id_categ'] . "&imovel=" .
    $destaque['imov_id'] . "&galeria=" .
    $destaque['imov_id_galeria'];

// chamada na api, convertendo a url
$destaque['share_whatsapp'] = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55" .
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row_share['Something is wrong_whatsapp']) .
"&text=" . rawurlencode($url);

// resposta
echo $destaque['share_whatsapp'];
```

Irá retornar esse comando:
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55123456789&text=Ol%C3%A1%2C%20gostaria%20de%20conversar%20%C3%A1%20respeito%20deste%20im%C3%B3vel%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fimoveis.php%3Fcategoria%3D99%26imovel%3D99%26galeria%3D99

Veja mais sobre url aqui:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rawurlencode.php

Espero ter ajudado. Avisa se funciona. :)